# Pure CSS Descending Z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

While technically I can fix my own problem with a little bit of jQuery, the question sparked my curiosity; **can an unknown number of elements be z-indexed in descending order?**

Here is my issue more specifically. I have an unknown number of `div`s that will be created by PHP in a `foreach` loop. The issue is that the background of these `div`s are (in areas) transparent and are designed to overlap. Using negative CSS `margin`, I can easily pull the elements to overlap one another, but the problem is that by default, css renders them with seemingly higher indices as they go down.

**To illustarte what I mean, [here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4EbPR/)**

After thinking on this for a few days, I haven't been able to come up with an answer. So, to you. Any ideas?

P.S. If anyone is coming here strictly for a jQuery solution, here it is:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(index) {
    zindex = index * -1;
   $(this).css('zIndex', zindex);
});
```

Comment: don't know of a way to do this with CSS. My first question would be "why on earth do that?"

Comment: Can't you just reverse the array you're looping over in PHP before the loop begins?

Comment: @Bryan good thought but the order has to stay the same.

Comment: @BiAiB because unfortunately javascript isn't always enabled on the client's browser.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be adding inline styles in the PHP loop.

If you know the length of the object you are looping through, you can easily calculate the inline style.

This is not the most elegant solution, but it will always work.

Answer (score 1):

[Sort of](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/4EbPR/1/), but it's not very generic:

```
div:nth-last-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;
}
div:nth-last-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
div:nth-last-child(3) {
    z-index: 3;
}
div:nth-last-child(4) {
    z-index: 4;
}
div:nth-last-child(5) {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

You could just write out hundreds of these rules, or you could generate the CSS with the same script/loop you're writing the elements out with.  Or you could just include the `z-index` in an inline style on the element.

All in all, I think the jQuery approach is better - does it cause a functional problem for users without JavaScript enabled, or is it just aesthetic?

Comment: ahh! inline styles from php! that's brilliant. i knew I was missing something. thanks! however I guess that means that there isn't actually a way to do it in just CSS. It was mostly curiosity anyway. +1 for a great solution.

Comment: @AndyL No, I think any elegant CSS solution would have to wait until [a future implementation of CSS variables](http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b49w0) - but [don't hold your breath for that](http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables).